# How can I use setfacl to give no access to "other" users?

Tags: permissions, acl

The command `setfacl -dm g::rwx mydir` sets permissions for groups to read-write-execute.  I'd like to run a similar command such that other users (i.e. **not** the owner) have no access whatsoever, but `setfacl -dm o:: mydir` complains that option `-m` is incomplete.  What is the proper way of expressing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An empty permission set can be represented with `-`:

```
setfacl -dm o::- mydir
```

This doesn't appear to be documented, so I don't know how portable it is. However, the documentation does mention that they can be specified as an octal digit (4 r, 2 w, 1 x, as in chmod), so:

```
setfacl -dm o::0 mydir
```

Comment: It is documented in the FreeBSD `setfacl` manual page.  It was also in the original TRUSIX _Rationale_'s manual page for the `setacl` command.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  I'm glad (in a sense) that the documentation is lacking -- I was beginning to think I just wasn't "getting it"!